# Do we need both @Transactional and @Modifying annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am still trying to wrap my head around how @Transactional works.

I have `@Transactional` annotation on Service class's method and `@Modifying` annotation on the method in the Repository class. Does method with `@Transactional` annotation applies to the method in the Repository with annotation `@Modifying`?

My understanding:

> `@Transactional` on a method of a class with `@Transactional( readOnly
>   = true )` no data gets written to the database, whereas with `@Transactional`, the data gets written to the database.

Modifying Queries

> 1. Modifying method signature can only return `void`, `Integer` or `int`
> 2. **Updating queries MUST be transactional, mark with `@Transactional`**
> 3. **Spring Data will drop all non-flushed changes pending in the `EntityManager`, change with `@Modifying(clearAutomatically=false)`**

As the second point says `@Modifying` queries must have `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`, so we can either add it at `@Service` level method call or `@Repository` method level call. If added at the `@Service` level it applies to the `@Respository` method too which is being called from the `@Service` level method call?

Example:

```
@Service
class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

@Autowire
AnimalRepository animalRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public void persistAnimal() {
....
animalRepository.save();
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void checkIfAnimalPresent() {

...
animalRepository.checkIfPresent();

}

@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteAnimal() {
...
animalRepository.deleteAnimal();
}
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public interface AnimalRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository {

@Modifying
@Query(...)
void save();

@Modifying
@Query(...)
int checkIfPresent() 

@Modifing
@Query(..)
int deleteAnimal();
}
```

My question is around:

1. Why do we need `@Transactional` in the service class when we have it at the repository `@Repository` level and I have `@Modifying` on methods
   which modify the entity and writes it to the database (only because I have `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` at the class level) ?
2. Does the annotation `@Transactional` on the Service class propogate to `@Repository` class?

I hope I am very clear with my questions and examples here.

Comment: You aren't really clear (imho). Yes you need `@Transactional` when modifying data even with `@Modifying` that is only an annotation to let Spring Data know you have a `@Query` that changes stuff. The `@Transactional` marks the start AND end of a transaction. If you put it in your service layer everything called from within a single method participates in the same transaction. If you don't every call inside that single method will become its own transaction.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I have one last question, I already have Transaction annotation at the Repository level (however readOnly=true). What happens when I have modifying on my query and I have no Transaction at the service level but I have one at the repository level with readOnly = true, will the Entity be written/updated in the database ? Somehow it worked for me when I accidentally forgot to annotate the Service level method with Transaction annotation.  I am new to string, jpa and hibernate so bear with me.:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This how `@Transactional` works:

By default, CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional.
For read operations, the transaction configuration `readOnly` flag is set to `true`.
All others are configured with a plain `@Transactional` so that default transaction configuration applies.
If you need to tweak transaction configuration for one of the methods declared in a repository you can override that method and add `@Transactional` annotation with required attribute values.

Another way to alter transactional behavior is to use a facade or service implementation that (typically) covers more than one repository.
Its purpose is to define transactional boundaries for non-CRUD operations.

If you use this approach, the transaction configuration at the repositories is then neglected, as the outer transaction (defined in the service layer) configuration determines the actual one used.

Reference: [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation - 5.7. Transactionality](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

Comment: I've found more precise quote "By default, CRUD methods on repository instances inherited from SimpleJpaRepository are transactional".