# Execute a query using javax.ws.rs api with no return type

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs

I wish to execute a query

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0 ;
```

What I normally do for a get request

```
public void setSafeMode() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = client.target(URI.contextPathUI + "/api/orderbook/safeMode").request().get();
    }
```

At the backend controller

```
@GetMapping("/orderbook/safeMode")
    private void setSafeMode() {
        orderBookRepository.setSafeMode();
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface OrderbookRepository extends JpaRepository<Orderbook, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
    @Query(value="SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0 ; ", nativeQuery = true)
    void setSafeMode();
}
```

I know it should not be a get request but we dont have an execute method in this api. I expected to run this get request and return a void. It gives an error

```
    "message": "could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query"
```

What I want is to know how to execute a simple query which does not return something AND I do not have to pass an entity or anything else(unlike I have to in a PUT or POST query) because it is not logical.
This query does not require any external inputs could be just rebuild a table and Insert it into another table.

Comment: change the return type from `void` to `int` and does this query is valid ?

Comment: It gives an error " o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding @Modifying and @Transactional annotations to the repository method

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;", nativeQuery = true)
void setSafeMode();**strong text**
```

Important links to learn more

[Do we need both @Transaction and @Modifying annotation in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314475/do-we-need-both-transaction-and-modifying-annotation-in-spring?rq=1)

[why do we have to use @Modifying annotation for queries in Data Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665090/why-do-we-have-to-use-modifying-annotation-for-queries-in-data-jpa)