# How to run queries like "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0" with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wish to run this query in my spring desktop application

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Should it be a GET request or a PUT request ? I have tried both but no success.
Currently I am trying

```
@GetMapping("/orderbook/safeMode")
    private void setSafeMode() {
        orderBookRepository.setSafeMode();
    }
```

```
@Query(value = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;", nativeQuery = true)
    void setSafeMode();
```

But it gives an error

```
2019-10-18 11:38:37.844 ERROR 12112 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
2019-10-18 11:38:37.851 ERROR 12112 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
```

any suggestions please

Comment: Try adding `@Modifying` annotation to repository method

Comment: it says "message": "Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked by adding @Modifying and @Transactional annotations to the repository method

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;", nativeQuery = true)
void setSafeMode();
```

Thanks to `Nikolay Shevchenko` for suggesting @Modifying annotation

Important links to learn more

[Do we need both @Transaction and @Modifying annotation in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314475/do-we-need-both-transaction-and-modifying-annotation-in-spring?rq=1)

[why do we have to use @Modifying annotation for queries in Data Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665090/why-do-we-have-to-use-modifying-annotation-for-queries-in-data-jpa)

Answer (score -1):

Here is right flow to update an object in DB using Spring Data:

```
// first go get that object by id, ex :
OrderBook orderBook = orderBookRepository.findById(1);
// 
if (orderBook != null) {
    orderBook.setSafeMode(0); // setter
    orderBookRepository.save(orderBook); // updating if object already have id and the id is existed in DB or will save new object if there are no id existed in DB.
}
```

**EDIT**
If you find way to lock object for update with Spring Data JPA

> PESSIMISTIC_READ – allows us to obtain a shared lock and prevent the
>   data from being updated or deleted

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
public Optional<OrderBook> findById(Long id); // override
```

When you call orderBookRepository.findById(1) first, then other can't update it until you already committed that object.

Comment: but i am not trying to update an orderbook object here. I want to run the query 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;' and asking how to do it because we do not have an execute query method in JPA

Comment: Ahh, I see. you need something like `Select * from table for update;` ? thing like that?

Comment: not really !! I am precisely trying to run the query(not update anything) I mentioned. I know how to update an object through spring framework using JPA.

Comment: I haven't mentioned it anywhere that I want to get an orderbook object by id or update or save it.

Comment: Okay lah :), maybe I don't understand your question.